# A single word to describe an object is difficult to stand, walk or balance on due to it's size

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I am looking for a word that describes an object that is difficult to stand, walk or balance on due to it's size. The object itself is firmly in place and does not move or wobble, but is still difficult to balance on, let alone walk across it. The object in question is bridge in a video game where the character can easily fall off because the bridge narrow. The word "narrow" may suffice, but I would like a word that makes you feel like it would be almost impractical to balance on it. In this context, the bridge has to be crossed in order to win a reward.

Comment: ***Unweildy***.

Comment: When I looked up Unweildy, I found words like heavy, weighty and massive. These do not describe the bridge in a way that makes it seem narrow and difficult to balance on.

Comment: you are correct, I misread your question originally. perhaps ***precarious***?

Comment: Maybe the the bridge is "ototoxic" : toxic to the sense of balance.

Comment: @DanBron Not ***precarious*** because *The object itself is firmly in place and does not move or wobble*

Comment: The bridge is *dangerous* or *too narrow*. [10 highly dangerous bridges](http://www.wonderslist.com/10-highly-dangerous-bridges/)

Comment: I ended up changing my idea so that in the game it is a very unsteady, rickety bridge. This way precarious, narrow, unsteady and of course, dangerous all fit the description now.

Comment: @kiseochan If only life were so easy…

Comment: In this context, I would use the word _treacherous_. But since you changed it... oh well.

Comment: It’s probably not strong enough of a word (and certainly not strong enough for an answer), but in a comment I’d dare to say that such a bridge sounds quite “pedestrian-unfriendly"!

Answer (score 1):

I would offer **precipitous** here as it seems to fit the description of the situation over a precipice.

[Description number 2 here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/precipice) states "a situation of great peril" but is also generally taken to mean on the edge of something that you might fall from.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find a word for the bridge itself
(except for ***wobbly***, which I see,
upon rereading the question, you've ruled out). 
But you might be able to use words that describe
the physical act of crossing it:
***dizzying*** and ***vertigo-inducing***. 
Similarly dangerous acts could be called
***daring***, ***death-defying***, or ***perilous***.